# How to get Manifest.mf file content from a jar file

Tags: java, collections, manifest, executable-jar, manifest.mf

I have a jar file named "**mail.jar**" .I have extracted the jar file through java code.
Now I have manifest file present under "D:/Test/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" location.[This is the image of Manifest.mf file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79GXE.png).
Any way I am able to read to Manifest file by the help of **FileReader** and **BufferedReader** and print it to the console.
In the manifest file ,below specifications r present.
                   (1)Manifest-Version:
                   (2)Archiver-Version:
                   (3)Created-By:
                   (4)**Export-Package:**

Now my doubt is how to get all the package list under **Export-Package:** tag only .
Can anyone help me here ??
Any help will be appreciated.

O/P should display like below screen shot.
[Expected O/P screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMtYY.png)

Regards,
AD

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It is unclear what you want to do or need.

Comment: Solomon,Are you getting my requirement here now ? Plz let me know if any doubts you have to under stand the question ...

Comment: Probably with the [Manifest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/Manifest.html) class. Create an object with an input stream from your manifest file.

Comment: You can read the manifest file if you use the java.util.jar.JarFile and than call getManifest(). From than, use getMainAttributes().getValue('Export-package') and split that string using .split(',')

Comment: Sorry but can you clarify your question? Do you have problem with *accessing* manifest file, or with *parsing* it? Also how does your code look like?

Comment: Peshmo,this is regarding facing problem in accessing specific attribute of manifest file content.

Answer (score 1):

Hi solomon & PeterMmm,
         Thanks for your help.
now I am able to access the manifest file content for specific attribute.
Below is the code snippet I am using:-

```
public class ReadmanifestFile {
public String getManifestAttributes() throws IOException {
    String value = null;
    File file = new File("G:/AD/JAR_FILES/mail.jar");
    if (file.isFile()) {
        JarFile jarfile = new JarFile(file);
        Manifest manifest = jarfile.getManifest();
        Attributes attributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();
        value = attributes.getValue("Export-Package");
        String[] arr = value.split(";");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

}

click the below for Output for above code snippet:-
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1szx.png)

I think this is right way to do.Plz let me know if I can improve the code snippet  in any of the other ways.

regards,
AD